# Bad performance with a big UI layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout

In the beginning I had an activity with some fields on it. As time goes by the layout becomes too big, so now I need to refactor it.

Currently on Samsung Galaxy S8 the activity needs ~2 seconds to show up, on an older device this number is 4-5 seconds, which is terrible.

Does anyone has a tip for me where should I start the refactor? I thought about to put the bottom section in a recyclerview, but the rows are quite different, and the full content must be scrollable (plus there is a `HorizontalScrollView` for the images). I'm using Glide for loading images.

Layout file: [layout xml](https://pastebin.com/Dc4FcdL2).

Screenshot: [screenshot from actual screen](https://ibb.co/mmYtS0).

## Update1:

Maybe some kind of dynamic data loading can help me? For example show the 'empty' fragment after the UI inflate and then dinamcially set the fields from top to bottom.

Comment: Maybe you should use fragment ? Like module, for exemple fragment for display picture etc, like that you'r going to explode you'r layout in different part

Comment: Use fragment. Too much scroll for one page layout. That's why it cause a 2 -5 seconds to appear.

Comment: Thanks both of you. How should I break the attached long fragment into smaller parts? The fragment is in a ViewPager (with a map fragment). What UI control should I use to replace my solution and accomplish what you are suggesting? UI control, design pattern, every suggestion should be helpful. How will the render be faster if I break a big thing to many little? The system have to process the same amount of view, isn't it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I've chosen [AsyncLayoutInflater](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/AsyncLayoutInflater), so far it seems a good choice for my problem.

Sample code:

```
AsyncLayoutInflater asyncLayoutInflater = new AsyncLayoutInflater(getContext());
asyncLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lake_more_data, mLakeDataContainer, new AsyncLayoutInflater.OnInflateFinishedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onInflateFinished(@NonNull View view, int resid, ViewGroup parent) {
        // set UI elements with data
        // ...

        parent.addView(view);
    }

}
});
```